# struct ip_mreq disappears when compiling with -std=c99

Tags: c, linux, sockets

On some of our linux boxes compiling with gcc -std=c99 makes struct ip_mreq disappear (included from netinet/in.h)

Is there some other interface we are supposed to use ?

Comment: what do you mean with "dissappear"? Can you provide an actual compiler/linker error message?

Comment: using cpp i can see the struct is defined or not depending on the presence of -std=c99

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try --std=gnu99.

The default for GCC is '--std=gnu89' which means C89 with GNU extensions. By selecting '--std=c99' you are enabling C99, but disabling the GNU extensions. '--std=gnu99' will select both C99 and GNU extensions support, giving you the best of both worlds.

Comment: Or use `-std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's another interface pre-c99. You may be able to use this with `-std=c99` if you add the following at the top of your source(s):

```
#define __EXTENSIONS__
```

but a better way is probably

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

Please note that I haven't confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem. Everything compiles fine using gcc when I do not provide "-std=c99", but when the flag is included, the compiler fails saying that the field with type 'struct ip_mreq' "has incomplete type."

This is a problem since I am dependent on some C99 features.